# Sonido con nueva línea en EditText

Tags: java, android-studio

sigo con mi pequeña App de android (con android studio), quería saber si es posible que después de cada línea nueva (\n) sería posible emitir un sonido. 
Esta app funciona en una PDA con lector de código de barras con laser y mi pretensión es que tras cada lectura en su editText emita un sonido "error.mp3" si el código leído tiene menos de 8 dígitos.

Ya probé a añadir ese sonido con un botón, el que utilizo para guardar el fichero y suena pero no es eso lo que busco.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String correo;
String contrasena;
Session session;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
    correo="Pda1.unitech@gmail.com";
    contrasena="Misstic01*";
    EditText etTexto = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.etOrigen );
    EditText etTexto2 = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.etDestino );
    EditText etTexto3 = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.etEdad );
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.error);


    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.error);
    // vinculado al botón de guardar
    Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnSaludar);

    mp.start();

}

// botón para guardar fichero
public void btnSaludar_Click(View view){
    //Acceso a Tienda origen
    EditText etOrigen =(EditText)findViewById( R.id.etOrigen );
    //Acceso a Tienda destino
    EditText etNombre =(EditText)findViewById( R.id.etDestino );
    //Acceso edad
    EditText etEdad =(EditText)findViewById( R.id.etEdad );
    //TextView tvSaludar = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tvSaludo );
    // variable solo texto
    String solotexto=etNombre.getText().toString(); // string del nombre tienda origen
    int Destino_T = Integer.parseInt(solotexto);
    String Destino_t =String.format("%6d", Destino_T);
    String strorigen=etOrigen.getText().toString(); // string del nombre tienda origen
    int Origen_T = Integer.parseInt(strorigen);
    String Origen_t =String.format("%6d", Origen_T);
    String letra_t = getString(R.string.letra );
    String unidad_f = "0000000001";
    String codbarras = etEdad.getText().toString(); // string de edad que es codbarras
    String codbarras_1= codbarras.replaceAll("\\n|\\r", "            0000000001\n");

    String cadena = codbarras;
    int contador = 0;
    int indice = cadena.indexOf("\n");
    while (indice >= 0) {
        contador++;
        indice = cadena.indexOf("\n", indice + 1);
    }

    String[] items = codbarras.split("\n");

    String CadenaFinal = "";
    for (String item : items)
    {
        CadenaFinal += ("T"+Origen_t+Destino_t+ String.format("%-25s",item)+"0000000001\n");

    }

    // variable que utilizo actualmente //
    String saludo = CadenaFinal; //O directamente usar CadenaFinal y eliminar saludo.

    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,"Código leidos: "+contador,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    // fecha y hora fichero //
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", new java.util.Date());
    long msTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date curDateTime = new Date(msTime);
    // nombre fichero //
    final String nombre="TRASPASO_T-"+Origen_T+" A T-"+Destino_T+"__"+ curDateTime+".csv" ;

            // Creo el fichero
    try {
        File tarjetaSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Toast.makeText(this, tarjetaSD.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File rutaArchivo = new File(tarjetaSD.getPath(), nombre);
        OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo =new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(rutaArchivo));
        //OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(nombre, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));
        crearArchivo.write(saludo);
        crearArchivo.flush();
        crearArchivo.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        etOrigen.setText("");
        etNombre.setText("");
        etEdad.setText("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo guardar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}
nada estoy muy espeso
no logro contar los caracteres entre cada '\n' salto de línea
con esto tengo el recuento de caracteres pero sin lograr reiniciar el contador al aparecer un salto de línea

```
 if(before==0) {
                counter = 0;
                num=0;
                for (int i = 0; i < text.toString().length(); i++) {
                    if (text.toString().charAt(i) == '\n') {
                       counter++ ; }// counter++;                }
                }
            }
```

Espero que alguien pueda encaminarme un poco, gracias

Comment: Con la función keyPress, verificas si la tecla es un salto de línea y reproduces el sonido.

Comment: Gracias, voy a investigar

Comment: Buenas otra vez , debo estar muy espeso porque no soy capaz de contar de hacer un contador de caracteres entre cada '\n' salto de línea.

Answer (score 0):

Con éste listener en tu texto verificas si la tecla presionada es un salto de línea.

```
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Verificas si la tecla es enter
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Aquí reproduces el sonido y llamas al toast
          Toast.makeText(this, any, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Buenas, con esta parte de código que me has dado funciona la parte en que no es la tecla "ENTER" , lo que utilizo es una PDA, y me dice el log que los botones que pulso son: ** 03-06 11:16:08.617 1606-2700/? I/System.out: KEYCODE_SCAN pressed
1606-2700/? I/System.out: KEYCODE_SCAN released ** ; pero si en el código pongo "KEYCODE_SCAN" me da error.

Comment: Si le cambias a (keyCode == el número Int) que te devuelve la tecla enter?

Comment: Pregunta tonta de donde saco ese numero Int ?

Comment: En el debug agrega un punto de interrupción en el if e inspecciona KeyEvent y el KeyCode

Comment: Gracias, y ahora tengo otra duda, resulta que si el escaneo es bueno me dice que el keyCode = 66 y el event = keyEvent(ACTION_UP, keyCode= KeyCode_Enter ......   ; si por el contrario no lee nada me dice keyCode = 138 y event= keyEvent(ACTION_UP, keyCode= KeyCode=193 ...; pero sigue sin darme resultados en el toast

Comment: El toast de mi código debes cambiarlo por el toast de tu código, Lo puse como ejemplo por eso no debería funcionar.

Comment: Si ya lo he cambiado y solo me funciona en la parte donde se supone que es falso

Comment: Y cambiando la condición con ACTION_UP y keyCode == 66 tampoco funciona?

Comment: Te refieres a esto ** if (keyCode == ACTION_UP || keyCode == 66 )** , ya lo probé y tampoco

Comment: if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) && keyCode == 66)